# Javascript mouse click (down/up) not called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have a problem with the call of `onmousedown`.

I have a web page (HTML) in which I want to annotate several images (it's about making garbage tags on images). I made a slider with a button <kbd>next</kbd> and <kbd>previous</kbd> to go from one image to another.

it looks like this:

[image]

this picture is the first, index `0` (can be seen on the console). the rectangles are added to the "canvas" by clicking on the class in the menu on the left. Each image has its "canvas" (we notice that the "canvas" is also index 0 so it's the "canvas" of the image).

In order to move the rectangles, I use `onmousedown` / `onmouseup` and it works, everything works well on the first image.

But on the second and the following, it doesn't work.

[image]

After clicking on the <kbd>next</kbd> button (hidden by the console on the screenshot). We see that the image and the canvas have changed, index is `1`, the previous rectangle is redrawn on this canvas (as wanted) but when I click on the rectangle to move it, I can't and I don't even have the `console.log` of recent clicks like on the previous screenshot. I click but nothing happens, the function is not called. I put an `onclick = alert (id)` directly in the HTML canvas tag to see if it works and yes, it works. I have an alert with the right id at the right time when I click in the "canvas".

So I can add and move (onmousedown, onmouseup) rectangles on the first canvas of the first image, I can pass with the button "next" to the next image and its "canvas", the "redraw" rectangles of the previous image is done, but nothing happens when I click on the "canvas", the call of the function is not done, otherwise I will have logs in the console.

Any idea?

Here is a little code from a different part.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="containerCaptures">
    {% for capture in captureSelectionOfTagSession %}
        <div class="jsoda-workspace">
            <canvas class="jsoda-canvas"></canvas>
            <img src="{{ capture.image.url }}" alt="{{ capture.name }} class="jsoda-image" id="{{ capture.id }}">
        </div>
    {% empty %}
        <div>
            <p>Aucune image.</p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

**JavaScript for image slider:**

```
var currentIndex = 0,
items = $('.containerCaptures div'),
itemAmt = items.length;

function displayFirstImg(){
    var firsItem = $('.containerCaptures div').eq(currentIndex);
    firsItem.css('display','inline-block');
    loadImage();
}

function cycleItems() {
    var item = $('.containerCaptures div').eq(currentIndex);
    items.hide();
    item.css('display','inline-block');
    loadImage();
}

$('#btNext').click(function() {
    currentIndex += 1;
    if (currentIndex > itemAmt - 1) {
        currentIndex = 0;
    }
    cycleItems();
});

$('#btPrev').click(function() {
    currentIndex -= 1;
    if (currentIndex < 0) {
        currentIndex = itemAmt - 1;
    }
    cycleItems();
});
```

And in **another JavaScript file:**

```
function loadImageOnStart() {
    image = document.getElementsByClassName("jsoda-image")[currentIndex];
    console.log("ici loadImage");

    console.log(currentIndex);

    var jsodaCanvas = document.getElementsByClassName("jsoda-canvas")[currentIndex];
    jsodaCanvas.width = image.width;
    jsodaCanvas.height = image.height;
    console.log("ici loadImageCanvas");
    console.log(currentIndex);

    mousedown = false;
    x1 = -1;
    y1 = -1;
    x2 = -1;
    y2 = -1;

    redraw();
}

document.getElementsByClassName("jsoda-canvas")[currentIndex].onmousedown = function(e) {
    console.log("onmousedown");
    console.log(currentIndex);
    mousedown = true;
    clickedArea = findCurrentArea(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
    if (clickedArea.box != -1) {
        for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
             boxes[i].selected = false;
        }
        boxes[clickedArea.box].selected = true;
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
            boxes[i].selected = false;
        }
    }
    x1 = e.offsetX;
    y1 = e.offsetY;
    x2 = e.offsetX;
    y2 = e.offsetY;
    redraw();
};
```

That's just a piece of the whole code, code is long...

Don't hesitate to ask if you need more information.

Comment: When you use `document.getElementsByClassName("jsoda-canvas")[currentIndex].onmousedown` in your script, you're assigning the click handler to a **single** element, namely the very first `<canvas>` (since at the time of the call, `currentIndex` is `0`). You are never assigning a click handler to `document.getElementsByClassName("jsoda-canvas")[1]` for instance.

Comment: thanks, so wich part have to be change ? I'm little confused

Comment: You need to wrap the `onmousedown` assignment in a `for (var i = 0; i < itemAmt; i++)` loop and use `document.getElementsByClassName("jsoda-canvas")[i]`

Comment: thank you very very much it's work. Very bad mistake